# Issue with passing multiple input values to Like clause in SOQL query. Any workaround please?

Tags: soql

I am trying to run this query in Query Editor but got

> "Unknown error parsing query"

Is there any workaround for this?

```
Select Customer_Name__c From SAP_Customer_Master__c where Customer_Name__c like ('trimax%','thomas%')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that with a like, you'd need to use OR instead:

```
Select Customer_Name__c From SAP_Customer_Master__c where Customer_Name__c like 'trimax%' or Customer_Name__c like 'thomas%'
```

**EDIT**

Something that I didn't know, that I've only just found out from trying it, is that you can use LIKE with bind variables. So, whereas the SOQL in the OP wouldn't work due to a compilation error, this would:

```
Set<String> names = new Set<String>{'trimax%', 'thomas%'};
List<SAP_Customer_Master__c> masters = [Select Customer_Name__c 
From SAP_Customer_Master__c 
where Customer_Name__c like :names];
```

Comment: Thanks @Phil Hawthorn. Would that be too tedious to construct a query if there is a big list of string for instance a 500?

Comment: Agreed, that would be very tedious but only a little more tedious that typing like ('trimax%', 'thomas%'). Editing my answer.